# Is eth0 only actual interface in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, ethernet, u-boot

I am confuse among various interfaces of ethernet .I am just going through this U-Boot Link

http://www.denx.de/wiki/DULG/UBootEnvVariables

Where it says

ethaddr: Ethernet MAC address for first/only ethernet interface (= eth0 in Linux).

Now my confusion is eth0 is only real interface whose address is programmed into efuse register

Is other interfaces like eth1 ,eth2 and so on virtula interface which will be configured by applcation later on .

Also from this link

http://e2e.ti.com/support/arm/sitara_arm/f/791/t/209421.aspx

Where it says

The MAC addresses programmed into the internal e-fuses will be from the TI address pool.  Customer will need to add some type of storage device (Flash, EEPROM) which contains their MAC addresses if they want to use addresses from their own address pool.

Now are these two mac address one written in e-fuse and other in Flash by customer two different address for eth0?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to discover something about a particular piece of hardware.  It might help to ask a slightly broader question.  I'm guessing yours is something like this: "Does the TI Sitara processor model number XXX have one or two hardware ethernet interfaces?  I'm using the development board YYYYY.", followed by maybe "How can I configure the second interface with UBoot", or "How do I set up a virtual network interface?".

Answer (score 1):

This uboot documentation is for many different kinds of hardware, some of which have only 1 interface, and some of which have more.  The language "Ethernet MAC address for first/only ethernet interface (= eth0 in Linux)" just means that referenced variable is for eth0, which is the first ethernet interface.  If there is only one interface, it is still called eth0.  If your hardware has multiple ethernet interfaces, the other variables are for them.

Regarding the second question: it appears that this hardware device has a built-in ethernet controller, which needs a unique MAC address to function on a network.  The device ships with a MAC address already configured (written into the e-fuse of the device, and therefore read-only).  If you don't want to use that MAC address, you can instead use flash or EEPROM to store your own MAC address to configure the ethernet controller.  Only one of those choices will be active.

One reason you might want to change the MAC address is that MAC addresses are assign in blocks to different vendors, and the shipped address is from the TI block.  That means network analyzers will think the overall product is a TI device.  If you want your product to appear as a different vendor, you need to use your own MAC address drawn from your own pool.  If you don't know what this means, don't worry about it: use the one that is preconfigured and built-in.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your thoughts and made quite a sense to me.May be silly question but having two ethernet interfaces(eth0 and eth1) means two ethernet controllers and how Do I say a Particular harware has more than one interface?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  It looks like the Sitara processor (is that what you're using) has two ethernet devices.  I see this in the datasheet for the processor.  They'll show up as eth0 and eth1.  The processor is installed on a board.  The board may connect only one interface to a physical connector, or it may connect both.  Are you struggling with a particular board?

Comment: Well Peter its Keystone Board I'm exploring ,The point I wanted to know is two on board these two interfaces are drived by one controller ,is it like having two separate NIC cards?

Comment: At the user level (looking at available interfaces), two interfaces on one controller is exactly the same as two controllers each with one interface.  If you're doing advanced networking things, there may be a slight difference, for example if you try to use a hardware switching function between the two ports.

Comment: Peter would explain your above point bit more(you try to use a hardware switching function between the two ports)?

Comment: Just an example of something advanced, which may or may not be supported by your device.  If you don't know what it means, don't worry about it.  Two interfaces is two interfaces, move on.